# What are the various ways of drawing things to a picturebox in VB6 and what are the advantages of each?

Tags: vb6, drawing, picturebox

I know of two ways:

1. Using the .line, .circle, etc. methods
2. Using bitblt
3. PaintPicture (never used it; found it on google)

Are there any others?

What are the advantages to using a certain system over the other? (speed, anti-aliasing, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line and Circle are for vector graphics. Line draws lines, rectangles, and squares. Circles draws ellipses and circles. You can control whether these methods are outlined or filled, the line width, and the foreground an background colours.

BitBlt is an Win32 API call (not a built-in VB feature) which allows you to write a bitmap to a device context (which a PictureBox has). There are a number of different modes which allow you to interact the pixels of the background you are drawing onto with the pixels of the graphic).

The PaintPicture() method is essentially a COM wrapper around BitBlt, with bitmap handles being replaced by Picture objects.

There is also PSet, which simply draws a dot are the specified location on the screen. And I suppose you could also include Print, which allows you to draw text (which could potentially contain graphics fonts).

If you go to the Win32 API, there are a host of other graphics functions for drawing other shapes such as arcs, polygons, and bezier curves. However, they are generally more difficult to use than the built-in VB methods.

As for the advantages of ones over the others, it is basically:

- VB features vs. Win32 API features : ease of use vs. power
- Vector graphics vs. Bitmap graphics : more flexible, but more programming required vs. simple, but uses more memory.

Comment: Can you comment on whether or not these various methods can do anti-aliasing?  I'm guessing not for the native VB methods.  Is there a speed difference?  Can I mix and match the native VB methods and BitBlt / Win32 API?  Like if VB's Line, Circle, etc. methods are faster, but I want to support bezier curves as well, would it be possible to use both at the same time?

Comment: None of them do antialiasing natively. Your best option is to draw large and resample down.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw I recently used `SetPixelV` from Win32API, which I found to greatly outperform `.Pset`.  You didn't mention this particular API function, but I figured I'd mention it as being very much worth using.  You have to use `.Refresh` afterwards to update the picturebox's displayed image, but it still ended up being twice as fast.

Comment: @Deanna When you say "resample down"... I tried `PictureBox1.Scale(...)-(...)` using zoomed out boundaries, but that didn't perform any AA for me.  Do I have to write a custom function for this to average all of the sub-pixels being represented?  I've never used `.Point` or calls to win32api's `GetPixel` so many times, but I can only imagine that the performance will be bad, which unfortunately makes it pretty infeasible for me, as my display has to update in real-time.

Comment: I don't work with anything other than pixels sizes for graphics. I created an image 10x (in each dimension) the target size, draw it at that large size, then resample (with `StretchBlt()`) into the target picture.

Comment: @Michael - doesn't surprise me at all. Just for interest, are you using AutoRedraw = True ?

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw Yep.  My guess is that `.AutoRedraw = True` only causes VB6 to refresh the image if you use a native manipulation of that image, not an API-based manipulation.